# Ionic 2 - Slide left to remove

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a list of items in my app. This is the code

```
                   <ion-list>
                        <ion-item-sliding #item *ngFor="let productSize of productSizes">
                            <ion-item>

                              ... some stuff

                            </ion-item>
                            <ion-item-options side="right">
                                <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="RemoveItem(productSize)">X</button>
                            </ion-item-options>
                        </ion-item-sliding>
                    </ion-list>
```

When the user slides left, there is a button delete that shows up and lets the user to delete the item.

I want to do this without the remove button. When he slides left and releases the mouse or touch, delete the item.

Comment: Listening for events (ionDrag) and (ionSwipe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the expandable option combined with the (ionSwipe) event.
So your options will look like this:

```
<ion-item-options side="right" (ionSwipe)="RemoveItem(productSize)">
```

and your button:

```
<button ion-button color="danger" expandable (click)="RemoveItem(productSize)">X</button>
```

Check out the docs [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/ItemSliding/#usage) (under Expandable Options).